# Delete all files NOT containing a string & Rename files based on a pattern

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory that organizes files into other directories named after ID numbers.  Each of these directories contains icons as well as animation frames for graphical objects. I need to keep all files containing the string "icon"

Here is an example of a directory:

```
0501
|   05010000.effect.default.0.png
|   05010000.effect.default.1.png
|   05010000.effect.default.2.png
|   05010000.effect.default.3.png
|   05010000.effect.default.icon.png
|   05010000.effect.default.iconRaw.png
```

Afterwards, the directory should look like:

```
0501
|   05010000.effect.default.icon.png
|   05010000.effect.default.iconRaw.png
```

What would be even better is if I could also rename items in the directory to:

```
0501
|   5010000.png
|   5010000raw.png
```

respecting the original ID number for each image and deleting the leading 0.

This may not even be possible, but I have thousands of images that I need to do this for, so a manual process is not feasible.

Comment: I have almost no idea what commands do on any operating system, can you explain to me what the command is trying to do?

Comment: These are *nix commands, so that won't work with installing unixtools, cygwin or something similar. I'm working on a Windows solution right now. Concering the renaming part - you removed the leading 0 in the filename, is that intentional?

Comment: I have deleted my comment - I have no idea why but I thought it was a unix question.  So ignore that suggestion - I will write an actual answer for a Windows batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below will do the deleting and the renaming both.  But the substitution used to create the new filename for the rename is case sensitive so the filenames must be lower case like in your example.

This doesn't actually do the deleting and renaming - it just prints the commands to the screen.  Remove the ECHO in front on the DEL and REN commands to have the commands executed.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /S /B *.png ^| FINDSTR /V icon') DO (
    ECHO DEL %%G
)
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /S /B *.png ^| FINDSTR icon') DO (
    SET X=%%~nG
    SET Y=!X:.info.icon=!
    ECHO REN %%G !Y:~1!%%~xG
)
```

The first for loop deletes the incorrect files (identical to the answer by @zb226) and the second loop renames the files we are keeping.

How it works is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /S /B *.png ^| FINDSTR /V icon') DO (
   ...
)
```

The FOR executes the command in single quotes which finds the files to delete and then runs the commands after the DO once for each filename found (with the filename in `%%G`).  The command that finds the files uses DIR to do a directory listing (/B returns just the filename and /S recurses the subdirectories) and then uses FINDSTR to filter the filenames by returning filenames that don't contain `icon` (/V returns things that don't match).

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /S /B *.png ^| FINDSTR icon') DO (
   ...
)
```

The FOR executes the command in single quotes which finds the files to rename and then runs the commands after the DO once for each filename found (with the filename in `%%G`).  The command that finds the files uses DIR to do a directory listing (/B returns just the filename and /S recurses the subdirectories) and then uses FINDSTR to filter the filenames by returning filenames that do contain `icon`

```
SET X=%%~nG
SET Y=!X:.info.icon=!
REN %%G !Y:~1!%%~xG
```

Lots of stuff is happening here:

- `X=%%~nG` assigns just the filename stored in `%%G` to X
- `!X:.info.icon=!` removes `.info.icon` from the filename.
- `!Y:~1!` removes the first character (the leading zero), so `!Y:~1!` is the new filename and `%%~nG` is the old filename.
- Now `%%G` is the full drive, path, filename and extension of the old file and `!Y:~1!%%~xG` builds the filename and extension of the new file.

Comment: I did not read your answer fully. I do need to have it search subfolders because each file is stored inside of another folder that has the first 4 numbers of its ID. For example: `.\item\etc\0400`. this is why my example was laid out the way it was. Sorry for being so dependent.

Comment: I don't know why I thought you didn't need to recurse into the subdirectories.  I have edited my answer to handle that.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of the help. I feel like I should be learning this stuff on my own, but this is the first time I am doing a big enough project that doings things manually is too tedious. I also used the wrong file name in the example above, but I assume changing `!X:.effect.default.icon=!` to `!X:.info.icon=!`, which is the correct name, will fix the problem.

Comment: It does not seem to be working as intended. I have been messing around a bit with what you wrote even 5 hours ago, but I cannot seem to get it to work on my own. I uploaded a small sample of the directory before ever running the command, with the batch file in the same relative location that I am executing it from. https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0bfli6bzhz7sld/Item.wz.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Wulfre How embarrasing.  REN doesn't take a drive letter and path as part of its second argument.  You can tell I only ran it with the ECHO statements in...  It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

The following batch file needs to be executed from the folder containing all your folders like the example folder `0501`. The script does not actually delete anything yet, it just prints out the deletion commands. Remove the `ECHO` when you're confident that the solution does what you want.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /S /B *.png ^| FINDSTR /V /I icon') DO (
    ECHO DEL %%G
)
```

Comment: Or `forfiles /S /M *icon*.png /C "cmd /c echo @file"` might work.  Obviously, the for loop is better if you are going to rename the files...

Comment: This works great. I wish I could understand it too. I can read what it does, I would just never be able to remember how to recreate it. I figure doing what I wanted with the renaming is going to be much more complicated, but this definitely helped with removing all of the bloat from my directory.

Comment: @Wulfre: Glad to have helped :) [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/) has a nice set of pages on the Windows command set - if you should consider diving into the batch file esoterica ;)